# Is there any standard Java Component with a notification count

Tags: java, swing

I am wondering if there is a Standard Java Component (Icon or JLabel) that offers the abillity to show a notification count like the example below. I am not doing Android Development. I just want to show something similar in a Java desktop client application

[image: Example]

The following code in a JLabel subclass would get the same result, but I am more interested in a standard solution. Which automatically derives the correct font size and automatically adjust to the visible space.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  int w = getWidth();
  Font orgFont = g.getFont();
  Font deriveFont = orgFont.deriveFont(8.5f);
  g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
  g2d.fillOval(w - 12, 0, 12, 12);
  g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
  g2d.setFont(deriveFont);
  g2d.drawString("99", w-10, 10);
  g2d.setFont(orgFont);
}
```

Comment: Nope, nothing in Swing. It was developed when these things were far from standard, and  mostly has more general components (save maybe a file/color chooser). You need to find an external library, or make your own decorator.

Comment: Perhaps class [`JLayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) is appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is a Standard Java Component (Icon or JLabel)

No there is no standard component.

You might be able to:

1. Use the [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/). It allows you to combine multiple icons into one.
2. Add a second JLabel with the notification Icon to the first JLabel. By default a JLabel doesn't have a layout manager but there is no reason you can't use one.

So for example to add the label in the top/right corner you could do:

```
JLabel main = new JLabel(…);
main.setLayout( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5) );

JLabel notify = new JLabel(…);
main.add( notify );
```

Comment: nice ideas. I will give it a try.